# Datetime.Now.ToString("HHmm") changed behavior

Tags: c#, .net, tostring

I'm using this line of code to set a string value with the current hour:minute in a 24 hours format. For example 14:50.
The problem is that now it's 14:50 PM here and this function returns 02:50, which is AM and causing a big problem. Any idea how did it suddenly changed in all of our servers? Both in test and production.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure you checked the time (-zone) of your servers, didn't you?

Comment: look like your clock is wrong on your servers ?

Comment: "Suddenly" and "all servers" has just one explanation.  They are actually off by 12 hours.  Easy mistake, in a server farm usually one machine is the authoritative time provider, ensuring that all machines are in sync.  A domain controller is a common choice.   Talk to your LAN admin, he can find help at serverfault.com

Comment: The clock on the servers shows the correct time.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet around this statement?

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm")` will not result in "02:50" (or "0250" for that matter) if the 24-hour time is 14:50, [`HH` is always based on a 24-hour clock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#HH_Specifier). Whatever your problem is, it's not that statement (if that is the actual statement).

Comment: Please provide more information. Is there a global timezone set on application startup?? How are you able to reproduce te problem? 

And, why is a string causing a time-related problem? That stinks.. Are you casting it back to a DateTime object elsewhere?

Comment: You need to post a small amount of code that reproduces the problem and specify the versions of the .NET Framework, IIS, and the OS. Otherwise your question is probably going to get closed as being off topic

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Thank you very much. that is the correct answer.